# Extract vector from matrix based on column index changing by row

Tags: r, vector, indexing, extract

I am struggling with a theoretically simple problem with R:

say I have the following matrix:

```
a <- matrix(1:16,ncol=4)
```

and the following vector showing the column position I need to extract for each row:

```
b <- c(4,3,1,1)
```

I need to return the following vector:

```
[1] 13 10  3  4
```

In other words, for each row I need to extract the element whose column position is shown in the corrisponding c value.

I have search extensively on this site but could not find a solution.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 a[cbind(1:nrow(a), b)]
 #[1] 13 10  3  4
```